# How to set maxbuffer for bitnami zookeeper chart?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, bitnami

I'm using bitnami zookeeper chart and its working fine. But, it's failing with large payloads. I wanted to configure maxbuffer for Zookeeper. Earlier the zookeeper had the below property to configure maxbuffer. FYI. [https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#:~:text=jute.maxbuffer%20%3A%20(Java%20system%20property%3Ajute.maxbuffer)](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.2/zookeeperAdmin.html#:%7E:text=jute.maxbuffer%20%3A%20(Java%20system%20property%3Ajute.maxbuffer)).

> -Djute.maxbuffer

But with the new bitnami chart, I'm not able to find a similar kind of property to set maxbuffer. Any suggestion ? I am using the reference https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/zookeeper/values.yaml